Failed to send transaction using safe structure local access to Sepolia
I used safe infrastructure to locally access Sepolia and successfully created a safe account. However, when I tried to sign and transfer funds using Safe launched by Docker, the proposal failed due to a 500 Internal Server Error
The following error occurred in the cgw container
{"build_number":"3f0937f","level":"error","message":{"chain_id":"11155111","client_ip":"192.168.65.1","detail":"An error occurred","method":"POST","origin":"http://localhost:8000","path":"/v1/chains/11155111/transactions/0x739AD7B3bb0795D2f485B0D9Ae920827b0c60F0b/propose","response_time_ms":1055.7053749999031,"route":"/v1/chains/:chainId/transactions/:safeAddress/propose","safe_app_user_agent":null,"status_code":500},"request_id":"e1896e1f-b018-4741-b4a2-5e39523d5461","timestamp":"2024-07-12T03:09:34.799Z","version":"v1.51.0"}

This is my chain configuration
{
  "count": 1,
  "next": null,
  "previous": null,
  "results": [
    {
      "chainId": "11155111",
      "chainName": "sepolia",
      "shortName": "sep",
      "description": "",
      "chainLogoUri": "http://localhost:8000/cfg/media/chains/11155111/chain_logo.png",
      "l2": true,
      "isTestnet": true,
      "rpcUri": {
        "authentication": "NO_AUTHENTICATION",
        "value": "https://sepolia.infura.io/v3/a8fd70fa80a3484ab0afcdcc8935fabd"
      },
      "safeAppsRpcUri": {
        "authentication": "NO_AUTHENTICATION",
        "value": "https://sepolia.infura.io/v3/a8fd70fa80a3484ab0afcdcc8935fabd"
      },
      "publicRpcUri": {
        "authentication": "NO_AUTHENTICATION",
        "value": "https://sepolia.infura.io/v3/a8fd70fa80a3484ab0afcdcc8935fabd"
      },
      "blockExplorerUriTemplate": {
        "address": "https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/{{address}}",
        "txHash": "https://sepolia.etherscan.io/tx/{{txHash}}",
        "api": "https://sepolia.etherscan.io/api?module={{module}}&action={{action}}&address={{address}}&apiKey={{apiKey}}"
      },
      "nativeCurrency": {
        "name": "sepolia",
        "symbol": "ethereum",
        "decimals": 18,
        "logoUri": "http://localhost:8000/cfg/media/chains/11155111/currency_logo.png"
      },
      "pricesProvider": {
        "nativeCoin": "ethereum",
        "chainName": "sepolia"
      },
      "balancesProvider": {
        "chainName": "sepolia",
        "enabled": false
      },
      "transactionService": "http://nginx:8000/txs",
      "vpcTransactionService": "http://nginx:8000/txs",
      "theme": {
        "textColor": "#ffffff",
        "backgroundColor": "#000000"
      },
      "gasPrice": [],
      "ensRegistryAddress": null,
      "recommendedMasterCopyVersion": "1.4.1+L2",
      "disabledWallets": [],
      "features": [
        "CONTRACT_INTERACTION",
        "DOMAIN_LOOKUP",
        "ERC1155",
        "ERC721"
      ]
    }
  ]
}

Please let me know what is the root cause and how to fix it.
Additionally, if I need to activate a local chain ID and shortName that are not in shortNameMapping, how should I configure it
Thank you.

Thanks for reporting this! Would you be able to provide more information on the transaction data? Since Safe creation worked, the problem could come from invalid transaction parameters; without more details it will be difficult to help you debug it.
Thanks in advance! Best, Louis
